# How to select row by key column in O(1)? (Python Datatable)

Tags: python, datatable, py-datatable

How can I get the row by key value in O(1)?

The only way I found in the docs to select rows is the row selector that seems to not take advantage by the keyed status of the column.

For example in this table:

```py
size = 10**4
DT = dt.Frame({'id':range(size)})
DT.key = 'id'
```

Access using a row selector is really slow compared to access by row number:

```py
for i in range(size):
    DT[dt.f.id==i,:]
# ~2.61 s

for i in range(size):
    DT[i,:]
# ~0.03 s
```

Since the column is keyed my expectation is to be able to access in O(1), but I don't know the right way to achieve this.

Comment: At the moment, the only feature of a keyed column is its use in joins; I do not think that it has been optimized or implemented for selection.

Comment: thanks sammywemmy, actually seems that you are right

Answer (score 0):

Simulating row selector with join gets you faster result:

```
for i in range(size):
    dt.Frame(id = [i])[:, :, dt.join(DT)]
# ~0.4 s
```

I believe that creating an intermediate frame `dt.Frame(id = [i])` is the slow part.

Comment: nice workaround, but actually it's useful if I need only to read data, if I also need to update selected row this is unsuitable, right?

Comment: yeah, I followed the title of your question literally: "How to select a row by key". In case of update this exact solution doesn't apply.